# Pass additional parameters to bind?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two functions that look like this:

```
  primaryImageLoaded () {
    this.setState({primaryImageLoaded: true})
  }

  secondaryImageLoaded () {
    this.setState({ secondaryImageLoaded: true })
  }
```

They are called like this(using react):

```
onLoad={this.secondaryImageLoaded.bind(this)
```

This feels excessive and I would like to have just one function and pass the state-variable as a parameter, but how can I pass an additional argument to [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)? and is it possible to use a variable as key in the object i'm passing to `setState`?

Comment: Add your parameter as the second argument of bind

Comment: Did you look at the [documentation for bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can pass additional arguments to bind that will be passed when your function is invoked:

`this.secondaryImageLoaded.bind(this, arg1, arg2)`

If you are using ECMAScript 2015 and onwards, you can use a [variable as a key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) by wrapping it in square brackets:

```
this.setState({
    [myVar]: value
});
```

So you could rewrite it to be more like:

```
function imageLoaded(which) {
    this.setState({
        [which]: true
    });
}

onLoad={this.imageLoaded.bind(this, 'secondary')}
```

Comment: I've never seen the square brace syntax before. Would you mind providing an explanation or a url that provides more info?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Comment: Note, that [] notation is only for ECMAScript 2015 onwards. Edited answer to clarify

Answer (score 2):

You can use arrow function for definition your function, and this way you don't need bind method.

```
secondaryImageLoaded = () => {
    this.setState({ secondaryImageLoaded: true })
  }
```

After that, in your jsx code:

```
onLoad={this.secondaryImageLoaded}
```

If you want know more about that you read [this article](https://medium.com/@joespinelli_6190/using-arrow-functions-to-avoid-binding-this-in-react-5d7402eec64)