# TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.onPressDropdownData(this.data).bind')

Tags: react-native, expo

I want is to record my inputs involving checkbox selection, dropdown selection and everything else into an alert box. I am having trouble with capturing the dropdown selection and checkbox selection into a state and further placing all those inputted details into an alert box.

Below is the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
    Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, Button
}
from 'react-native';
import {
    Header, Icon
}
from 'react-native-elements';
import {
    Constants
}
from 'expo';
import {
    CheckBox
}
from 'react-native-elements';

import {
    createStackNavigator,
    createNavigatorContainer
}
from "react-navigation";

import {
    Dropdown
}
from 'react-native-material-dropdown';

export
default class UpdateFrequency extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'UPDATE FREQUENCY',
        style: {
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            backgroundColor: "#FFD700"
        }
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // this.toggle= this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            ischecked: true,
            data: '',
            time: 0
        }
    }
    onChangeCheck() {
        this.setState({
            ischecked: !this.state.ischecked
        });

    }
    onPressDropdownData(data) {
        this.setState({
            data: data
        });

    }

    onPressDropdownTime(time) {

        this.setState({
            time: time
        });
    }

    render()

    {

        const data = [{
            value: '3 Hours'
        }, {
            value: '6 Hours'
        }, {
            value: '12 Hours'
        }, {
            value: 'Daily'
        }];

        const time = [{
            value: '6 AM'
        }, {
            value: '00:00 HRS'
        }];

        return ( < View style = {
                styles.container
            } >

            < Text style = {
                styles.writeup
            } > Use this page to select how many updates you would like to receive at once. < /Text>

        <View style={StyleSheet.create({flex:1})}>


        <CheckBox style={styles.one}
            center
            title="Receive Simultaneously"
            checkedIcon="dot-circle-o"
            uncheckedIcon="circle-o"
            checked={this.state.ischecked}
            value={this.state.ischecked}
            onPress={this.onChangeCheck.bind(this)}
          / >

            < Dropdown label = '# Updates to Receive'
            data = {
                data
            }
            onPress = {
                this.onPressDropdownData(this.data).bind(this)
            }
            />


        <Dropdown
        label='Delay Between Updates'
        data={time}
        onPress={this.onPressDropdownData(this.data).bind(this)}
        / >

            < TouchableOpacity style = {
                styles.adsense
            }
            onPress = {
                () = > {
                    alert('Receive simultaneously : ' + this.state.ischecked + '\n' + 'No. of updates to receive : ' + this.state.data + '\n' + 'Delay between updates : ' + this.state.time);
                }
            } > < Text > Show recorded inputs < /Text>
        </TouchableOpacity >

            < /View>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.adsense}>
        <Text>Adsense Ad</Text > < /TouchableOpacity>


      </View >
        );
    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column'
    },

    writeup: {
        flex: 0.3,
        backgroundColor: '#FFE4B5',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 8
    },
    adsense: {
        flex: 0.55,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#778899',
    },

});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add stack-trace to your question? Help community to help you

Comment: How to add a stack trace?

Comment: You wrote part of stack trace in title of your question: `Type error: undefined ...`. Copy full text of stack trace and add it to **text** of your question

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you cannot do this: `this.onPressDropdownData(this.data).bind(this)`.

Before all, I recommend to you using arrow functions for creating class methods. The arrow functions avoid you to do an explicit bind.

For solving your problem:

- If you want to pass extra parameters while binding, look this: [Pass additional parameters to bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304570/pass-additional-parameters-to-bind).
- If you want to access the `data` variable that you created in `render`, then you access only with the name of the variable, the reserved word `this` is for methods or properties that belongs to the class. I mean, only `data`, not `this.data`.

Links for read about the arrow functions:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html
- https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/when-to-use-arrow-functions